# How to make a View invisible/Gone onBackPressed() method in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-tabhost, visibility

I have 5 activities in a Tabhost. (i.e MainActivity.java  Home.java, NowReading.java, Favorites.java, and Profile.java). In the main activity I'm loading the tabhost, as show below.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    TabHost tabHost;
    Context context = MainActivity.this;
    TextView txt_Login;
    View homeTabLayout;
    View reviewLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_Login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Login);
        final Spinner spnrLanguage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrLanguage);
        final Spinner spnrBrowseBy = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrBrowseBy);

        tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Android tab
        Intent intentHome = new Intent().setClass(this, Home.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHome = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Home")
                .setIndicator("Home",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
                .setContent(intentHome);

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHome);

        Intent intentNowReading = new Intent().setClass(this, NowReading.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecNowReading = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Now Reading")

                .setIndicator("Now Reading",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.now_reading))
                .setContent(intentNowReading);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecNowReading);

        Intent intentFavourite = new Intent().setClass(this, Favorites.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecFavourite = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Favourite")
                .setIndicator("Favorites",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorites))
                .setContent(intentFavourite);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecFavourite);

        Intent intentProfile = new Intent().setClass(this, Profile.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecProfile = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Profile")
                .setIndicator("Profile",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile))
                .setContent(intentProfile);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecProfile);
tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("Home");
```

in the Mainactivity.java im setting The Home.java as current Tab. as

```
tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("Home");
```

which loads the layout home_activity.xml in the setContentView.

[image]

here is the XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_HomeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
        </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_ReviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_ReviewLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_image_borders"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/book1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_revwBookTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:text="The Basic Doctrine Of Islam"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_revwAutherName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_revwBookTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:text="By: Andrew J Newman"
                android:textColor="@color/SkyBlue"
                android:textSize="11sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_PublishDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_revwAutherName"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:text="Published: July, 30 2007"
                android:textColor="@color/DarkGray"
                android:textSize="11sp" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_PublishDate"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:isIndicator="false"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="5"
                android:stepSize="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOpenBook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ratingbar"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:text="Open Book"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnOpenBook"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnOpenBook"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnOpenBook"
                android:src="@drawable/pic_btn_back"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_BookOverview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Book Overview"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_BookOverviewDetails"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_OverVuBookCoverPhoto"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_BookOverview"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                android:lines="10"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, there was nothing that I can do she was dead, for this reasean I m gonna loose every thing consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

in the onCreate method of Home.java i have made a Framelayout invisible/Gone (which Contains the Overview of book Cliked) as

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        homeTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.rel_HomeLayout);
        reviewLayout = findViewById(R.id.scroll_ReviewLayout);
        reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

now when I click any book it make visible the view which i have made invisible/gone previously on the onCreat method as discussed above using the code

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(context, BookTitle.get(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

[image]

Note: that its not the new actvity rather I have just make Visible a view (i.e reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);) on the click event.

- I want to make this view Invisible/Gone on the onBackPressed() method.
- Where should I call this method, either in the MainActivity.java or in the Home.java file?
- If I'm calling this method in the MainActivity.java its raising a nullPointerException.

Comment: Instead of using TabActivity, you can use Fragments..
that will be better

Comment: Silent killer..! its not possible this time. please review my code and suggest me a solution plx

Comment: ohk no prob we have a method call 
onBackPress(){} in which you can hide the layouts or views..

Comment: i know this. this is not my question dude. i have asked something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **Override** BackPress method...
with help of this you can **Hide your Layouts or View...**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
               // Invisible or Gone Your Views here....
    }
```

Comment: @QadirHussain ask for suggestion here you will really got a good solution 
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13215/indian-enthusiastic-programmers

Comment: @SilentKiller i need to load  10 views inside backpressed but showing null pointer exception, but when i load one view its working fine.Can u tell me how to load many views at the same time

Comment: @Alliswell may be the memory have no more space so its remove the filled objects and you get NPE and without code I am helpless to help you.

Comment: @Alliswell that's pleasere.. :)

Comment: @SilentKiller i have one more doubt. can we place listviews on various position on our screen. If so can you please tell me home come to do that

Comment: @Alliswell you can have multiple listviews in a scree but you can not keep scroll with in scroll in android

Comment: @SilentKiller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377480/open-a-new-listview-from-previous-listview/19385830?noredirect=1#comment28819707_19385830 is que. I want to achieve my listview as like in the fig. Listview at various positions.

Comment: @Alliswell not getting the excat what you want can you show me some screenshots.?

Comment: @SilentKiller i need my listviews to be placed on different places. Now i resolved this issue by declaring everything inside linear layout :-)

Comment: @SilentKiller yes i resolved the issue and posted my code at the above link

Answer (score 3):

You can override back button method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // You can call view.setVisiblility(View.GONE) if you want to remove it from the layout, or view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) if you just want to hide it.
        view.setVisiblility(View.GONE); // or view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: thanks for rply where should i call this in MainActivit.java or in the Home.java?

Comment: add this where you want to hide view on back button.