# open a new listview from previous listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Hope you guys help me..

I have a listview with 5 rows in it. When i click a row it is opening another activity class. Now what i want is i would like to open a new listview instead of new activity on click. Totally i have 6 listviews.
I would like to open my new listview on the rightside of the previous listview so that both the listviews will be visible. 
my coding for onclick listener is

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt,
            long paramLong) {
        switch( position )
{
   case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, second.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity0);
            break;
   case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, third.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity1);
            break;
   case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, fourth.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity2);
            break;
   case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, fifth.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity3);
            break;
   case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, sixth.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity4);
            break;
}              
    }
});
```

[image: Here] is my expected output and when i click second row it should open new listview on the rightside of it.
Please help me in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you trying to do

Comment: @AT_AB is my layout and my question clear now?

Comment: (all is well from the 3 Idiots movie :) ) When you click on the second list view, what do you expected to happen ? –

Comment: @AT_AB I don't want any activities in my second listview. Its just a passive listview showing details about the particular row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, try this

First you have to do some changes on your layout xml file

> Layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fff123"
     />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ccc987"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- add other list as you like -->

</LinearLayout>
```

And other changes on your Activity like that

> Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView1;
    ListView listView2;
    String[] items = { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5" };
    String[] items_list_2 = { "items_list_2", "items_list_2", "items_list_2",
            "items_list_2", "items_list_2", "items_list_2", "items_list_2",
            "items_list_2", "items_list_2", "items_list_2", "items_list_2" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    new loadData().execute();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class loadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
            listView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items_list_2));
            listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item_list_2 : " + arg2,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            listView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

that's it, I hope this help you

For back button pressed you have to override onbackPressed method like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//hide the second list here
  listView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: thats working. can u please tell me how to hide the second listview when pressing back button? please

Comment: ok, I will edit my response, if this help you, make it as response (resolved) for other people

Comment: i would like to achieve 2 simple things 1) pressing backbutton should hide the new listview 2) new listview should open near the row which i press click e.g: if i press 3rd row from there my new listview should open(like in fig..) please guide me for this

Comment: for the back button I have edited my post, and for second point you have to achieve this on listView2.setOnItemClickListener listener, load new arrayList if you want and call notifyDataSetChanged on your list adapter, that's it

Comment: thanks for ur effort.. One more doubt.. i would like to add 6 listviews inside backpress event but it is shoe=wing null pointer exception when i load more than 1 view. If i load exactly 1 its working fine. Can u tell me how to load many views inside back press..

Comment: Yes, you have to instantiate all listviews in oncreate methode, firstly, move this line listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2) to onCreate and the same thing for others

Comment: Sir, This works great. But when am calling notifydatasetchanged my child view couldn't be opened at the position of the parent. as my listview is scrollable i need the child view to be opened on the position equal to its parent.

Comment: Your child listView will be opened next to your parent listView, and if you want the same size for both parent and child ListView, you have to change android:layout_height on your layout xml file

Answer (score 1):

You should use fragment to do this. In your FragmentActivity there will be two fragments. One fragment will contain the listview of 5 elements like you did. And the other fragment will contain a listView. When you click on one of the 5 elements , then you have to update the other fragment that holds the appropriate listview for that element. Probably the Settings app of Android Tablets is a good example of what you are trying to do.

See this link , might be helpful for you. You'll get what you need here.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html